# University assignment, cant run program as intended

Tags: c++, arrays, function, file, struct

So im trying to run a program that receives a set data from a file that updates each time the program is run and new data is added. But when i try to run it the program terminates after trying to receive input from user.The full code is as follow, im using devc++ if that matters

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

struct Deets
{
    string NameSite[];
    string AddressName[];
    int numVaccine[];
    int numStall[];
    string DateVax[];
    string ContNum[];
};


void Outputmenu();
int AddData(int,struct Deets V);
void EditData(int,struct Deets V);
void ShowExisting(int,struct Deets V);
void ClearArr(int,struct Deets V);
    
int main()
{
    int i;
    ifstream r("Total.txt");

    r>>i;
    r.close();
    
    Deets V;
    
    ifstream a;
    a.open("Data.txt");
    for(int c=0;c<=i;c++)
    while(a>>V.NameSite[c]>>V.AddressName[c]>>V.numVaccine[c]>>V.numStall[c]>>V.DateVax[c]>>V.ContNum[c]);
    a.close();
    
    int menuS;
    do 
    {
        Outputmenu();
        cout<<"\nPlease choose from 1-4, press 0 to close menu"<<endl;
        cin>>menuS;
        if (menuS==1)
            AddData(i,V);
        else if (menuS==2)
            EditData(i,V);
        else if (menuS==3)
            ShowExisting(i,V);
        else if (menuS==0)
            cout<<"Thank you for your cooperation, We hope to see you soon! \nClosing program..,";
        else 
            cout<<"Error, not within selection"<<endl;
    }
    while (menuS!=0);
    
    ofstream b("Data.txt");
    for(int c=0;c<=i;c++)
    while(b<<V.NameSite[c]<<" "<<V.AddressName[c]<<" "<<V.numVaccine[c]<<" "<<V.numStall[c]<<" "<<V.DateVax[c]<<" "<<V.ContNum[c]<<endl);
    return 0;
}

void Outputmenu() //instruction about the command for the user
{
    cout << "                          -hello there!-                           " << endl;
    cout << "===================================================================" << endl;
    cout << "            ***PLEASE CHOOSE ONE OF THE OPTION BELOW***            " << endl;
    cout << "===================================================================" << endl;
    cout << "\t1. Add Data (about Vaccination Center)" << endl;
    cout << "\t2. Edit Data" << endl;
    cout << "\t3. Show Existing Data" << endl;
    cout << "\t0. Close Program" << endl;
    cout << "===================================================================" << endl;
}

int AddData(int c, struct Deets A)
{
    
    bool rq;
    int i = c;
    cout<<"Enter your company name/ institute name : ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin,A.NameSite[i]);

    cout<<"\n\t\t Safety Measure"<<endl;
    cout<<"-Maintain a distance of 1 meter between one other access to vaccine doses.\n"<<"-Have a dedicated toilets for patient\n"<<"-Ability to maintain room temperature between 19 – 25 degrees \n"<<"-Have an adequate place for patients to wait  "<<"\n-Have adequate sharps disposal bins, appropriate for the volume of patients, and securely placed and spaced to mitigate the risk of needle stick injuries."<<endl;
    cout<<"-Adequate handwashing facilities for staff, and antimicrobial hand sanitizers available.\n"<<"-Store and handle COVID-19 vaccines under proper conditions, including maintaining cold chain conditions and chain of custody at all times in accordance with a EUA or vaccine package insert, manufacturer guidance, and CDC guidance in the Vaccine Storage and Handling Toolkit."<<endl;
    cout<<"-Appropriate security provisions to ensure no unauthorized access to vaccine doses."<<endl;

    cout<<"\nAre all requirement met? \n1:Yes \n0:No"<<endl;
    cin>>rq;
    if(rq == 1)
    {
        cout<<"\nWhere is the location : "<<endl;
        cin>>A.AddressName[i];
    
        cout<<"How many vaccines required : "<<endl;
        cin>>A.numVaccine[i];

        cout<<"How many vaccine stall can a site hold : "<<endl;
        cin>>A.numStall[i];

        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"Date for vaccine to be distributed"<<endl;
        getline(cin,A.DateVax[i]);
        
        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"Enter your management contact number : "<<endl;
        getline(cin,A.ContNum[i]);
        
        cout<<"Certificate for "<<A.NameSite[i]<<endl;
        
        i++;
        
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Thanks for the thought. We hope to cooperate with "<<(A.NameSite[i])<<" in the near future\n\n"<<endl;
        if(i>0)
        {
            i = i-1;
        }
        else
        {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
return i;
}


void EditData(int i,struct Deets A)
{

int c,EN,edit=0;
for (int c=0;c<i;c++)                    //showing all Company/Institute name data
{
    cout << c+1 << ". "<<A.NameSite[c]<<endl;
}

cout << "Enter number you would like to edit : ";  //asking user to enter which data user want to edit
cin >> EN;  //user enter which data they want to edit
c=EN-1;
cout << A.NameSite[c] << "\n" << "Do you want to edit this data? Yes:1 No:0"<<endl; //asking user whether they want to edit Company/Institute name
cin >> edit;
if(edit ==1) //if true, it will change the data
    cin >> A.NameSite[c];

cout <<"Total stall : "<< A.numStall[c] << "\n" << "Do you want to edit this data? Yes:1 No:0"<<endl; //asking user whether they want to edit total Company/Institute vaccine stall
cin >> edit;
if(edit ==1) //if true, it will change the data
    cin >> A.numStall[c];

cout <<"Adress : " << A.AddressName[c] << "\n" << "Do you want to edit this data? Yes:1 No:0"<<endl; //asking user whether they want to edit Company/Institute's address
cin >> edit;
if(edit ==1) //if true, it will change the data
    cin >> A.AddressName[c];

cout << "Contact number : " << A.ContNum[c] << "\n" << "Do you want to edit this data? Yes:1 No:0"<<endl; //asking user whether they want to edit Company/Institute's contact number
cin >> edit;
if(edit ==1) //if true, it will change the data
    cin >> A.ContNum[c];

cout << "Total Vaccine : "<< A.numVaccine[c] << "\n" << "Do you want to edit this data? Yes:1 No:0"<<endl; //asking user whether they want to edit total Company/Institute vaccine needed
cin >> edit;
if(edit ==1) //if true, it will change the data
    cin >> A.numVaccine[c];

cout << "Date of vaccine : "<< A.DateVax[c]<< "\n" << "Do you want to edit this data? Yes:1 No:0"<<endl; //asking user whether they want to edit Company/Institute's receiving vaccine date
cin >> edit;
if(edit ==1) //if true, it will change the data
    cin >> A.DateVax[c];

}

void ShowExisting(int i, struct Deets A) // void of ShowExisting that show the existing data stored in the program
{
for(int c=0; c<i; c++) //array to show all the existing data in the program so far
{
    cout << (c+1) << ". "<< endl; //number that show the count of which set of data shown
    cout << "Site Name: " << A.NameSite[c] << endl; //show the name of site in appropriate array of turn c
    cout << "Address: " << A.AddressName[c] << endl; //show the address of site in appropriate array of turn c
    cout << "Amount Vaccine: " << A.numVaccine[c]<< endl; //show the amount of vaccine needed in site in appropriate array of turn c
    cout << "Amount Stall: " << A.numStall[c] << endl; //show the amount of stall needed in appropriate array of turn c
    cout << "Vaccination Date: " << A.DateVax[c] << endl; //show the vaccination date in appropriate array of turn c
    cout << "Contact Num.: " << A.ContNum[c] << "\n" << endl; //show the contact number of the reprsentative from the site in appropriate array of turn c
}
}
```

The program runs until input when there is no data in the file but when there is data, the program wont even go past

```
for(int c=0;c<=i;c++)
    while(a>>V.NameSite[c]>>V.AddressName[c]>>V.numVaccine[c]>>V.numStall[c]>>V.DateVax[c]>>V.ContNum[c]);
```

please help as my caffeine brain is fried

*After considering everyone's response ive decided to rework the basis of the program with what everyone taught, Thank you for those who responded

Comment: Why are all the member variables of `Deets` arrays?

Comment: `while(a>>V.NameSite[c]>>V.AddressName[c]>>V.numVaccine[c]>>V.numStall[c]>>V.DateVax[c]>>V.ContNum[c]);` is going to create an infinite loop as the operations will always be true

Comment: `string NameSite[]` -- This and any lines looking like this are not valid C++.  Arrays must have their size denoted by a compile-time value.  Also `devC++` is not a C++ compiler -- it is an IDE.  The compiler that is used is probably g++.  In C++, dynamic arrays are done by using `std::vector`, i.e. `std::vector<std::string> NameSite;`.  Thus whatever you've been taught in C++, you've been taught incorrectly.

Comment: Also, `std::string` is in the `<string>` include, not `<string.h>`.  In addition, `int AddData(int c, struct Deets A)` -- there is no need to specify `struct` here.  That is a relic of `C` programming.  All you need is `int AddData(int c, Deets A)`.  Then you need to ask yourself why you are passing `Deets` by value.

Comment: In C++, you don't need to prefix types with `struct` when declaring variables or parameters.  For example, you can have `int AddData(int,Deets V);`

Comment: You should implement `operator>>` in your `Deets` class.  It would make your code easier to read.

Comment: Prefer to use `switch` when processing menu selection; IMHO, it's easier to read and debug than an `if-else-if` ladder.

Comment: Prefer to pass structures by reference.  This prevents the compiler from *making a copy* of the structure; instead, the compiler can emit instructions to access the structure directly.

Comment: Review your design.  You may want to have a `Deet` structure that contains one instance of every member and then a container of `Deet`.  Example:  `std::vector<Deet>` to hold all of your `Deet` instances.  This would simplify your program, especially when you overload `operator<<` and `operator>>` for a single `Deet` instance.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, *I* would rewrite/redesign your code rather than debug it.

Let's start by differentiating a single `Deet` from a *container* of `Deet`:

```
struct Deet
{
    string NameSite;
    string AddressName;
    int    numVaccine;
    int    numStall;
    string DateVax;
    string ContNum;
};
```

You can then overload `operator>>`:

```
struct Deet  
{
    //...
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Deet& d);
};
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Deet& d)
{
    std::getline(input, d.NameSite);
    std::getline(input, d.AddressName);
    input >> d.numVaccine;
    input >> d.numStall;
    std::getline(input, d.DateVax);
    std::getline(input, d.ContNum);
    return input;
}
```

You could declare a container and input the container like so:

```
std::vector<Deet> deet_container;
Deet d;
while (input_file >> d)
{
    deet_container.push_back(d);
}
```

BTW, you should always put descriptive variables inside your function declarations.  This gives people a better understanding of what the variables are and their positions.

Your function declarations could change:

```
typedef std::vector<Deet> Deet_Vector;
int AddData(int, Deet_Vector& V);
void EditData(int, Deet_Vector& V);
void ShowExisting(int, Deet_Vector& V);
void ClearArr(int, Deet_Vector& V);
```

By looking at `AddData`, the usage of the `int` first parameter is ambiguous.

- Are you adding an `int` to the container?
- Is the `int` the quantities of items to add to the container?
  Likewise with the other functions.

Next, I would add one function at a time to the program, compile and debug, then add another, repeat.

BTW, you can simplify your `Outputmenu` function:

```
void Outputmenu()
{
    static const char menu_text[] =
    "                        -hello there!-\n" 
    "===========================================================\n"
    "        ***PLEASE CHOOSE ONE OF THE OPTION BELOW***\n"
    "===========================================================\n"
    "\t1. Add Data (about Vaccination Center)\n"
    "\t2. Edit Data\n"
    "\t3. Show Existing Data\n"
    "\t0. Close Program\n" 
    "============================================================\n"
    ;
    std::cout.write(menu_text, sizeof(menu_text);
}
```

By using the `write` method, the text is written as a block and is usually a lot faster than using a lot of `operator<<`.